# For teachers : Improving oral communication skills in a language by identifying weak areas

Tags: learning-methods, teaching, teaching-methods

How often can you improve oral communication skills in a language where you have some level quickly by identifying weak areas and working of them?  (This could be the past tense or the most important strong verbs for example).

If so, is it easy for a teacher to work this way?
What about doing an assessment?

Are there other methodologies that work particularly well for "inconsistent level" learners with a lot of practice?

Practically I want to improve my French, and I do not want to ask something impossible from the teacher :-)
Also, this is the reason I think private classes is best for me.

I want the maximum short-term improvement in spoken French related to resources put in.

Obviously this depends on how you came to the level you have. In my case it is a long time since I have attended French language classes. I have been slowly improving by being in a French-speaking environment since then.  I can manage in French, but probably have a lot of basic errors.  I think my French is probably quite different from somebody who has just taken a lot of classes for example.

Comment: Welcome on Language Learning Stack Exchange! I am just wondering why you used teaching-related tags, since most of your description suggest that you are learning on your own?

Comment: Thanks for you comment.  I would not a teacher to do this, so so its about teaching-methods :-)  (In French, grammatical details are often not very important in spoken language)

Comment: I don't understand why you ask "how often" instead of simply "how".

Comment: I would also recommend focusing the question on how to *identify weaknesses*, because the question how to improve oral skills has also been discussed [here](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/907/800).

Comment: About "how".-- If you have a solid but limited base the situation is a bit different, Or the main issue might be vocabulary or similar "details".  Perhaps explicitly learning grammar is less important when you have some practice.

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe The other question and especially the answers are different, as that person have a lot of theoretical knowledge, but cant use it in practice while I have a lot of practice, and want to improve.